# push_backs to a std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<type>>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

Consider this attempt at `push_back`s to a `std::vector` of `std::reference_wrapper`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v_i;
  std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> s_i;
  for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
  {
    v_i.push_back(i);
    s_i.push_back(std::ref(v_i[i]));
  }
  std::cout<<v_i[0]<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<s_i[0].get()<<std::endl;
  return -1;
}
```

I expect the `[]` operator to return a reference to the `i-th` element of `v`, and from the possible implementation given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper#Possible_implementation), we can reasonably assume that the `std::reference_wrapper` object that is appended to `s_i` holds a copy of the pointer that points to the correct address of `v_i[i]`. However, the output of the code above is

```
0
1980603512 //or some other random garbage value
```

So obviously, the `std::reference_wrapper`s that are constructed inside the loop are pointing to temporary objects. Why does this happen, and what is the correct way of appending to `s_i`?

By the way, I am using `g++ 5.4.0` (with the `-std=c++0x` flag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> we can reasonably assume that the std::reference_wrapper object that
>   is appended to s_i holds a copy of the pointer that points to the
>   correct address of v_i[i]

No, you can't reasonably assume that. This is because any

```
v_i.push_back(i);
```

can result in reallocation of `v_i`; and in fact you're almost guaranteed that this is going to happen here, at some point. And any reallocation automatically, and immediately, invalidates all existing iterators and pointers to the existing contents of a vector.

This is no different if you saved any plain pointers to some elements in the `std::vector`, then attempted to `push_back()`, causing reallocation and invalidation of those pointers. Any subsequent dereference of those pointers results in undefined behavior.

What the shown code is doing here is substantively equivalent, just using an extra onion layer of `std::ref` to wrap the whole thing, but resulting in logically equivalent undefined behavior.

If you wish to avoid undefined behavior here, the only practical way to do so is to `reserve()` the vector sufficiently, as to guarantee that no reallocation will happen by the subsequent `push_back`()s.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `push_back` operation potentially invalidates iterators\references\pointers to the `std::vector` elements.

From [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and
>   references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.
>   Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

As your `std::vector` is growing, there is a moment in time when the new size is greater then the current capacity. As described above, it leads to the invalidation of references\pointers to the `std::vector` elements.

In this particular case, `std::reference_wrapper`s are invalidated.

Further usage of invalidated `std::reference_wrapper`s causes *UB*.